# Add leading zeros in alphanumeric string

Tags: r, string, alphanumeric

I have a character vector with strings with a similar format (letters, underscore, digits):

```r
v <- c("AB_124", "BAE_1", "LOED_1234", "H_01")
```

I want to add leading zeroes to have a length of 4 for the numerical part:

```r
c("AB_0124", "BAE_0001", "LOED_1234", "H_0001")
```

What are ways to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `stringr` solution that supplies a function (e.g. `str_pad`) into `str_replace()` to replace the match.

```r
library(stringr)

str_replace(v, "(\\d+)$", ~ str_pad(.x, 4, pad = 0))

# [1] "AB_0124"   "BAE_0001"  "LOED_1234" "H_0001"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using regex:

```
sprintf("%s_%04d", substr(v, 1, regexpr("_", v) - 1),
        as.numeric(substring(v, regexpr("_", v) + 1)))
# [1] "AB_0124"   "BAE_0001"  "LOED_1234" "H_0001"
```

Or stringr:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(v, "(\\d+)$", ~sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(.x)))
# [1] "AB_0124"   "BAE_0001"  "LOED_1234" "H_0001"
```

A bit simpler version of your sapply solution:

```
sapply(strsplit(v, "_"), \(x){ sprintf("%s_%04d", x[1], as.numeric(x[2])) })
# [1] "AB_0124"   "BAE_0001"  "LOED_1234" "H_0001"
```

Comment: we can also use `str_extract` with sprintf as `sprintf('%s%04d',str_extract(v,'^\\w+\\_'),as.numeric(str_extract(v,'\\d+')))`

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about it (but that I find a bit cumbersome), is to split and reunite:

```r
sapply(strsplit(v, "_"), \(x) {x[2] <- sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(x[2])); paste(x, collapse = "_")})
#[1] "AB_0124"   "BAE_0001"  "LOED_1234" "H_0001"
```

Answer (score 1):

Small variation, using `data.table`'s `tstrsplit` function

```
s <- data.table::tstrsplit(v, "_", type.convert = TRUE)
sprintf("%s_%04d", s[[1]], s[[2]])

# [1] "AB_0124"   "BAE_0001"  "LOED_1234" "H_0001"
```